# Change tab by click on a button angular material i am getting error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**ERROR** *"Cannot find name 'maxNumberOfTabs' "*
** My problem** i tried to navigate angular tabs with next and previous button in which i am getting error Cannot find name 'maxNumberOfTabs'
**This is ts file**

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Question, questionService } from 'src/app/services/question.service';
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material/tabs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logicaltest',
  templateUrl: './logicaltest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logicaltest.component.scss']
})
export class LogicaltestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent) {


  }
  ngOnInit() {
  //   setTimeout(() => {
  //     this.router.navigate(['']);
  // }, 120000);


  }
  selectedIndex: number = 0;
  nextStep() {
    if (this.selectedIndex != maxNumberOfTabs) {
     // console.log('in html page',row.Id);

      this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex + 1;
  }
    console.log(this.selectedIndex);
  }

  previousStep() {

    if (this.selectedIndex != 0) {
      this.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex - 1;
    }
    console.log(this.selectedIndex);
  }
 }
```

**this is html code**

```
    <mat-icon>arrow_back_ios</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button (click)="nextStep()">
      <mat-icon>arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
  </button>
    <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4];let i=index; ">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        </ng-template>
        content{{number}}
      </mat-tab>
```

Comment: `maxNumberOfTabs` isn't defined in any part of this code. I guess it should be 5. You can declare it as `const maxNumberOfTabs = 5;` at the top of the `nextStep` function.